# Bring canvas element to the front?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, canvas

I'm trying to make multipe cursors flying around my webpage. I got them working. My problem is that they're on top of an HTML5 and javscript `<canvas>` element. When they're over that, the other JQuery animations on I have on the page work fine, but it puts solid white over most of the canvas (which is a big, interactive, starfield). How can I fix this?

I can provide some of the code if needed, but the way I structured it, it relies on a lot of external scripts and style sheets, etc., so it might be a little fiddly.

Basically, I need to bring the canvas to the front while maintaining part of the JQuery animation.

EDIT: I thought it would be more helpful if I showed a picture showing the problem.

[image: Imgur]

You can see what remains of the starfield at the bottom. The place where the white stops and the starfield starts is the vertical constraint of the cursor animation.

I want to make the starfield show up over the background but under the cursors. Is there anyway, possibly, to set the background of the container (which is a `div` element) to a script with CSS, and use that script to animate the starfield? Then, I'd be able to max out the size of the container and give the cursors the full screen to fly around in.

Also, don't worry about the yellow alligator; it's a seperate JQuery animation that can be made a part of the background.

EDIT2: I think I figured out my problem, but I'm not sure how to fix it. To animate cursors within the containers, the `<div>`s for the cursors were within the container's `<div>`. The CSS for the the cursors was set for the highest z-index, but the CSS for the container was set for the lowest z-index. How can I fix this.

Again, I can provide scripts if necessary, but I believe that the most relevant one here is the one that animates the cursors, so I'll put here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    animateDiv($('.a'));
        animateDiv($('.b'));
        animateDiv($('.c'));

});

function makeNewPosition($container) {

    // Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
    var h = $container.height() - 50;
    var w = $container.width() - 50;

    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

    return [nh, nw];

}

function animateDiv($target) {
    var newq = makeNewPosition($target.parent());
    var oldq = $target.offset();
    var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);

    $target.animate({
        top: newq[0],
        left: newq[1]
    }, speed, function() {
        animateDiv($target);
    });

};

function calcSpeed(prev, next) {

    var x = Math.abs(prev[1] - next[1]);
    var y = Math.abs(prev[0] - next[0]);

    var greatest = x > y ? x : y;

    var speedModifier = 0.25;

    var speed = Math.ceil(greatest / speedModifier);

    return speed;

}
```

EDIT3:

It works! It works!

I took the other `<div>` elements out of the container. I had copied the script from another SO question, and the example there led me to believe that the `<divs>` had to be inside the container. But, when I put them outside, everything worked exactly as it was supposed to. Oh YEAH!

Thanks!
evamvid

Comment: You can add the CSS z-index property to the canvas element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With CSS you can change the layer of the element with the z-index property like so,

**CSS**

```
canvas { 
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

*Please note that because you said you're using a lot of style sheets, you might need to increase the z-index number to higher than 999 as a lot of plugins will set it to 999. Also for you to use the z-index property the element has to have the position property set*

Comment: Can I use the z-index property to manipulate other css elements?

Comment: @evamvid: You can use it to manipulate *any* DOM element. However, certain conditions must be fulfilled for the property to have any effect. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index.

Comment: the code I'm using sets up the canvas as `<canvas id="c"></canvas>`. Would the CSS given in the example have to become `#c { 
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
}`? Or would it stay the same, regardless of the canvas id?

Comment: @Mitch I'm accepting this because it didn't _quite_  solve my problem, but it put me on the path to it. With a little debugging, everything worked great!

Comment: @MitchLayzell thanks again for putting me on the path with the z-indexes!